# scss variable scope issue

Tags: css, sass

Why does `$var` in `.d2` get compiled to `4` instead of `3`?

```scss
$var: 0;

.a {
    $var: 1;
    z-index: $var; // 1
}

.b {
    z-index: $var; // 0
}

.c {
    .c1 {
        $var: 2;
        z-index: $var; // 2
    }

    .c2 {
        z-index: $var; // 0
    }
}

.d {
    $var: 3;

    .d1 {
        $var: 4;
        z-index: $var; // 4
    }

    .d2 {
        z-index: $var; // 4 ???
    }
}
```

Noticed this when using the `sass` npm package. Some web compilers output `3`, others `4`.

Comment: @EnenDaveyBoy "Makes the change"? There's no noticeable change in `.b` and `.c2`. So what makes `.d` so different? Also you fail to address the fact that some compilers output `3` and NOT `4`.

Comment: @AmauryHanser I've already read this page. None of this answers my questions.

Comment: When you do `$var: 3`, you're creating a new variable, scoped inside `.d {}`. You're assigning a new value here: `.d1 {.$var: 4 }`, but it's the same variable.

Comment: Makes sense. Sucks that this completely goes against how less and regular css do it and that every compiler outputs something different.

Comment: @bitcorisa Have you considere raising an issue with [sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass)? It might actually be a bug. The explanation given by Amaury doesn't sound convincing to me.